# Bizzare things happened when getting start time of today in java

Tags: java

I wrote the codes below to get the start time of today, my intention is to remove the passed milliseconds of today in order to get the start of it:

```
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long startTimeOfToday = currentTime - currentTime%(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    System.out.println(new Date(startTimeOfToday));
```

But the result printed is

> Thu Mar 19 08:00:00 GMT+08:00 2015

I know there must be something wrong with these codes, can anyone figure it out to me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get your local date without the time part, you should use a `Calendar`instead of a `Date`. Because `Date` doesn't know anything about timezones.

```
// this gives you the milliseconds of timezione GMT
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// you remove the milliseconds related to GMT
...
// you print the date related to your timezone, which has an offset of +08:00
System.out.println(new Date(startTimeOfToday));
```

A `Calendar` can handle the timezones.

```
// this gets a calendar for your default timezone
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
// remove the timepart of your timezone
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
// shows your local date at 00:00
System.out.println(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, your original calculations assumed that all days since the millisecond zero are 24 hours. That happens to be true for your system clock (and mine), but some clocks might account for leap-seconds.

Comment: @slim Don't understand your comment. Every day (independent from it's timezone' starts in it's timezone at 00:00. In my example I set the time of the local calendar to this time. There is no computation done, it's a simple set.

Comment: @suboptimal I was referring to op's original implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the midnight date for today:

```
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);

System.out.println(date.getDate());
```

In Java 8 you can use this:

```
LocalTime myMidnight= LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
LocalDate myToday= LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
LocalDateTime myMidnightOfToday = LocalDateTime.of(myToday, myMidnight);
```

Comment: I'm afraid you are not right. Actually I want a date time like 2015-03-19 00:00:00.

Comment: @tuanlong I don't understand your comment. How does this answer fail to give what you want?

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

Using the 2.7 version of the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime todayStart = DateTime.now( zone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Output:

> todayStart: 2015-03-19T00:00:00.000-04:00

A [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object knows it's own assigned time zone, unlike a java.util.Date object.